# Dynamic template values in angular.js ng:repeat iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a HTML table that uses a (dynamic) column model from the controller to render object properties depending on this column model.  I need the ability to change the order of the table columns that's we it's defined in the controller.

Here's an example:

```
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {
   // List of objects
  $scope.list = [
    { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3},
    { a : 2, b : 3, c : 4},
    { a : 3, b : 4, c : 5}
  ];
  // Properties to be displayed
  $scope.fields = [ "c", "b", "a" ];
});`
```

Template:

```
<table>
  <tr ng:repeat="item in list">
    <td ng:repeat="field in fields">
      {{item.<field>}}
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

So, item. should be something like item.[a|b|c] to render the value from either property a, b or c. But i got no clue how to get this condition working properly.

As i'm quite new to angular, i'm not sure if that's a good approach or if there is any other nice solution to render something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr ng:repeat="item in list">
    <td ng:repeat="field in fields">
      {{ item[field] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QTCDvCdIAP0ndB1jJDe7?p=preview